# Printing half size after board replacement

Tags: kossel

I recently burnt out one of the MOSFETS on my RAMPS 1.4 board on my Sintron Kossel clone so have upgraded it to a RAMPS 1.6.
Now my printer seems to only print 50 % of the intended size.

After the machine homes it only comes down about 50 % of the distance and so starts printing in mid air.

I thought it might have been the driver steps? The DRV 8825 drivers are 32 steps instead of 16. I changed this value in the firmware but it didn't make any difference.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What did you actually change than? You should adjust the steps per mm. If you go from 16 microsteps to 32 microsteps you need to send more steps (twice) to achieve the same distance to travel.

Answer (score 2):

Data from Firmware is not written into EEPROM on its own after updating your firmware. You need to send a `M502` to "seed" the firmware numbers as that is restoring the "default" settings in it. If you are unsure what is currently the EEPROM setting, use `M503` first.

Answer (score 1):

If you changed you stepper drivers here's a list to check:

1. Microstepping Jumpers
2. In Marlin Configuration.h:

- `X_DRIVER_TYPE`, `Y_DRIVER_TYPE`, `Z_DRIVER_TYPE` and
  `E0_DRIVER_TYPE`
- `DEFAULT_AXIS_STEPS_PER_UNIT`
- `INVERT_X_DIR`, `INVERT_Y_DIR`, `INVERT_Z_DIR` and `INVERT_E0_DIR`

3. In Marlin Configuration_adv.h:

- `MINIMUM_STEPPER_POST_DIR_DELAY`, `MINIMUM_STEPPER_PRE_DIR_DELAY`, `MINIMUM_STEPPER_PULSE`, `MAXIMUM_STEPPER_RATE`
- Other driver-specific constants

4. EEPROM settings stored on the control board (use `M503` to read current settings).

Comment: many thanks for the advice. will check those things out.cheers scott